# How to put a image and text on background image using Canvas or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I'm trying to put a image and text on background image using Canvas/jQuery, but i don't no how to do this. I need to do like this image http://static.catfly.com/quiz/which-friend-should-be-kidnapted-by-aliens/en/cover.jpg

I already tried and found some script for a blog but it's not complete script, it's only made a circle, anyone can help me please?

Here is my script below.

```
<body onload="displayImage()">

<script type="text/javascript">

    //Global variables
    var myImage = new Image(); // Create a new blank image.

    // Load the image and display it.
    function displayImage() 
    {
    // Get the canvas element.
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

      // Make sure you got it.
      if (canvas.getContext) 
      {
          // Specify 2d canvas type.
          ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

          // When the image is loaded, draw it.
          myImage.onload = function() {

          // Load the image into the context.
          ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);

          // Get and modify the image data.
          changeImage();
          }

          // Define the source of the image.
          myImage.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_image/843519123711803393/pyYe9LFq_400x400.jpg";
      }
    }

    function changeImage() 
    {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.lineWidth = "100";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 100, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    }
</script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is that the canvas is only 200x200 and the line width of the circle is 100, and white, so when drawn it fills most of the canvas (it's also drawn slightly outside the canvas area in this case).

And, the image in question also has a load error which may be the primary cause here (onerror+onabort handlers should always be added).

Simply adjust down the line width, fix the image, and I would also recommend setting the canvas bigger (it can be set using the image size).

Comment: I didn't asked to solve the included script, i want to make look like this image http://static.catfly.com/quiz/which-friend-should-be-kidnapted-by-aliens/en/cover.jpg